# summarise() in dplyr 1.0.2 acting like mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Given a `tibble` that lists users, products, and product features, I am attempting to calculate the fraction of distinct product users who have a certain product feature:

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tribble(
  ~users, ~product, ~feature,
  "bob","iPhone","screen",
  "bob","iPhone","camera",
  "bob","iPhone","facial recognition",
  "sally","Android","screen",
  "sally","Android","camera",
  "sally","Android","facial recognition",
  "joe","Huawei","screen",
  "joe","Huawei","camera",
  "joe","Huawei","facial recognition",
  "rachel","iPhone","screen",
  "rachel","iPhone","camera",
  "rachel","iPhone","fingerprint sensor"
)

# Get count of distinct users by product
df <- df %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  mutate(n_users = n_distinct(users)) %>%
  ungroup()

df
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    users  product feature            n_users
#>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>                <int>
#>  1 bob    iPhone  screen                   2
#>  2 bob    iPhone  camera                   2
#>  3 bob    iPhone  facial recognition       2
#>  4 sally  Android screen                   1
#>  5 sally  Android camera                   1
#>  6 sally  Android facial recognition       1
#>  7 joe    Huawei  screen                   1
#>  8 joe    Huawei  camera                   1
#>  9 joe    Huawei  facial recognition       1
#> 10 rachel iPhone  screen                   2
#> 11 rachel iPhone  camera                   2
#> 12 rachel iPhone  fingerprint sensor       2

# Count the fraction of distinct users with given product feature
df <- df %>%
  group_by(product, feature) %>%
  summarise(feature_fraction = n()/n_users,
            .groups = "drop_last")

df
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   product [3]
#>    product feature            feature_fraction
#>    <chr>   <chr>                         <dbl>
#>  1 Android camera                          1  
#>  2 Android facial recognition              1  
#>  3 Android screen                          1  
#>  4 Huawei  camera                          1  
#>  5 Huawei  facial recognition              1  
#>  6 Huawei  screen                          1  
#>  7 iPhone  camera                          1  
#>  8 iPhone  camera                          1  
#>  9 iPhone  facial recognition              0.5
#> 10 iPhone  fingerprint sensor              0.5
#> 11 iPhone  screen                          1  
#> 12 iPhone  screen                          1
Created on 2020-10-23 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

devtools::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United States.1252  
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252  
#>  tz       America/New_York            
#>  date     2020-10-23                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  backports     1.1.10  2020-09-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr         3.4.4   2020-09-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  devtools      2.3.1   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.2   2020-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  generics      0.0.2   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  lifecycle     0.2.0   2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pillar        1.4.6   2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  processx      3.4.4   2020-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.3.4   2020-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tibble        3.0.3   2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.0   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  utf8          1.1.4   2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  vctrs         0.3.4   2020-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  withr         2.3.0   2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  xfun          0.16    2020-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
```

As can be seen, the final `tibble` has multiple rows for group-key pairs with the same summary value. This is, to my knowledge, unexpected behavior for `summarise` and seems almost the same as what `mutate` would return. Given [this open github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5571), it appears that maybe all the kinks haven't been ironed out of the new version of `summarise`. I also could just be being stupid, and would appreciate if someone could help get me back on track!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your have multiple values for `n_users` for each group. The latest version of `dplyr` allow you to return more than one row per group if your summary function returns multiple values.

If you want to assume all the values for `n_users` will be the same per group, then you can do

```
df %>%
  group_by(product, feature) %>%
  summarise(feature_fraction = n()/first(n_users),
            .groups = "drop_last")
```

That will make sure only one value is returned per group

Comment: Not meaning to sound rude, but if you look through my code that is exactly what I have. Also, in this case the summary function does not return multiple values for the group-key pairs and yet is not summarised to a single row.

Comment: You have `n()/n_users`, not `n()/first(n_users)`. Those are different. In the first case `n_users` may have more than one value. `first()` will ensure only 1 value is returned. You could also use `unique()` if you assume they are the same. Older version of dplyr probably would have thrown an error.

Comment: @DanielMolitor You should try the code and look carefully before saying anything that sounds at all rude. `1 / c(2, 2, 2)` returns `c(.5, .5, .5)` and that's (essentially) what your code has, because each row has an `n_user` value. This answer changes it to `1 / first(c(2, 2, 2) = 1 / 2 = 0.5`. If you try this answer you'll see it solves your issue, and the explanation is accurate too.

Comment: Good point, thank you! However, given that in my case the values of ```n_users``` is the same for the entire group, I don't understand why the pre-dplyr 1.0.0 behavior would change. That seems likely to cause confusion (At least it did for me).

Comment: Yes - I agree it is confusing. It adds a lot of power to `summarize`, but I liked the clean `sumarize` -> 1 row per group interface, and I wish this was a new function with a new name. RStudio community forums or perhaps the `dplyr` GitHub repo would be places to have discussion about the design choices.